# A script to Get a query results

Tags: php

I will do a query using the search engine of brainspell.org, then I want to do a script that allows me to get the result of this query: "frontal network"

Image

[image]

In other words, I want to have the list of papers (title, x,y,z associated to the red points in the figure, ...)

Can anyone help me on this please

Comment: What you're describing is a project idea. SO is for specific programming problems you encounter while actually programming. If I'd ask you to provide the code you've tried so far to solve your problem, there probably would be none. And that's the problem.

Comment: I am not pretty sure that it is even possible to get the result of a php query since this would be a interpreted on the server side. Have you idea if i can even do this please.

Comment: Technically as long as it's data and follows some kind of computable algorithm, it should be possible. However, since you don't seem to have a background in programming, you could just politely request or propose this feature from/to brainspell.org . Asking first doesn't hurt. However, such a feature could cost a lot of time. Apart from that, using their data for your own project without asking their permission is also very questionable.

Comment: I see your point, regarding the integrity of the data, this is not problematic and i do not need to request this from Roberto (Brainspell' s developer) since it is a public project which is already on github. I was asking here because I think that it is not possible to get access to the data on the server side but now, after finding the data on github, I can just get the html format (list of titles as identifiers) then link to the titles  in the .xml file to get all themetadata I need. https://github.com/r03ert0/brainspell/blob/master/data/brainspell-15July2014.xml.zip

Comment: well if the data is all there ... ;oD